# Powershell WPF ListVIew with image column

Tags: wpf, powershell

I have been making GUI apps with PowerShell for a while with Windows Forms, but I am trying to transition to WPF.

I am trying to make a simple application with a ListView, that displays images/icons in one of the columns.

With the code that i have, i have just managed to display the path to the image but not the image itself.

_

If anyone could help me in the right direction it would be very much appreciated.

The code below

```
Add-Type -AssemblyName PresentationFramework

[xml]$xaml = @"
<Window
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    x:Name="Window" Height="600" Width="345">
    <Grid x:Name="Grid">
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
            <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"/>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"/>
        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <ListView Name="ListView" Height="500" Width="300" AllowDrop="True" SelectionMode="Extended" Margin="15,10,0,0" Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="0">
            <ListView.View>
                <GridView>
                    <GridViewColumn DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Image}">
                        <DataTemplate>
                            <Image Source="{Binding Image}" HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Top" />
                        </DataTemplate>
                    </GridViewColumn>
                    <GridViewColumn DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Function}"/>
                </GridView>
            </ListView.View>
        </ListView>
        <Button Name="Button" Content="Open" Height="30" Width="100" Margin="15,10,0,0" HorizontalAlignment="Right" Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="1"/>
    </Grid>
</Window>
"@

$reader = (New-Object System.Xml.XmlNodeReader $xaml)
$Window = [Windows.Markup.XamlReader]::Load($reader)

$xaml.SelectNodes("//*[@Name]") | %{Set-Variable -Name "$($_.Name)" -Value $Window.FindName($_.Name)}

$itemSource = @()

$Functions = ('Add Network Location','shell:::{D4480A50-BA28-11d1-8E75-00C04FA31A86}'),('Administrative Tools','shell:::{D20EA4E1-3957-11d2-A40B-0C5020524153}'),('Applications','shell:::{4234d49b-0245-4df3-b780-3893943456e1}')
$Functions | ForEach-Object {
    $itemSource += [PSCustomObject]@{
        Image = '<pathtoimage>\android.png'
        Function = $_[0]
    }
}

$ListView.ItemsSource = $itemSource

$Button.Add_Click({
    Start-Process explorer.exe -ArgumentList $Functions[$listView.SelectedIndex][1] -NoNewWindow
})

$window.ShowDialog()
```

Comment: Remove `DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Image}"` and move the DataTemplate into a `<GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>...</GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>` tag.